# If $M$ is a flat $R-$module and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, why is $I\otimes_R M$ isomorphic to $IM$?

Tags: modules, exact-sequence, flatness

This is often given as an equivalent property to $M$ being a flat $R-$module (for instance in one of the answers here [Are $I\otimes_{R}J$ and $IJ$ isomorphic as $R$-modules?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2036507/are-i-otimes-rj-and-ij-isomorphic-as-r-modules)). Certainly we can always map $I\otimes_R M \rightarrow IM$ by sending $i\otimes m $ to $im$, but it's not clear to me why (or if) this map has trivial kernel or how this relates to the flatness of $M$.

I have also tried thinking about exact sequences, for instance maybe we can start with an exact sequence of the form

$0\rightarrow I \rightarrow N$

for some module $N$ and then tensor by $M$. This would give the desired result since $M$ is flat, but it's not clear to me what the module $N$ would be since we would need to have $N\otimes_R M\cong IM$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try starting with the exact sequence $0 \to I \to R \to R/I \to 0$ and tensor with $M$.